# Toolbar in BaseActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, toolbar

I have multiple activities and fragments. I would like to set toolbar in BaseActivity (so set it only once). But need an acces to the toolbar from fragment (method like - show, hide, changeTitle etc.)
Any suggestion?

I have tried solution below, but when I want to hide fragment, NPException is shown

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  Toolbar toolbar;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getLayoutResource());
    configureToolbar();
  }

  protected abstract int getLayoutResource();

  private void configureToolbar() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
      setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
  }

 public void hideToolbar() {
   toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 }
```

My activity

```
public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity() {
}
```

I call hideToolbar in fragment like:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment() {

onCreate() {

((Myactivity)getActivity).hideToolbar();
}
```

Comment: Add more details to your question. How do you call the `hideToolbar` method inside your fragment?. How does the derived activity look like? You've just provided the abstract class definition and not the implementation  so difficult to answer where the problem lies

Comment: did anyone find an answer for this?

Answer (score 4):

I have include something like yours in my project. This is sample. You can take reference from it.

`BaseActivity.java` class:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(getLayoutResource());
    }


    protected abstract int getLayoutResource();
}
```

`ToolBarActivity.java` class:

```
public abstract class ToolbarActivity extends BaseActivity {
protected Toolbar toolbar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View contentView = findViewById(R.id.flToolbarContentContainer);
    if (contentView instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ((ViewGroup) contentView)
                .addView(LayoutInflater.from(this)
                        .inflate(getToolbarLayoutResource()
                                , (ViewGroup) contentView, false));
    }
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 }

 @Override
 protected int getLayoutResource() {
     return R.layout.activity_toolbar;
 }

 protected abstract int getToolbarLayoutResource();

 public void showToolbar() {
     toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }

 public void hideToolbar() {
     toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 }
}
```

`activity_toolbar.xml` layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rlToolbarContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/pbToolbarActivity"
    android:background="@color/blue_panel_day_background"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/flToolbarContentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

`MainActivity.java` class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ToolbarActivity {

@Override
protected int getToolbarLayoutResource() {
    return R.layout.activity_main;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    homeFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.llMainActivityContainer, homeFragment)
            .commit();
}
}
```

`activity_main.xml` layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/llMainActivityContainer"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, in `Fragment` class, apply:

```
 ((ToolbarActivity) getActivity()).showToolbar();
 ((ToolbarActivity) getActivity()).hideToolbar();
```

Comment: what is createNavbar method?

Comment: Ohhhhhh!!! that is a method for `Navigation Drawer` .It doesn't need there.

Answer (score 0):

From Fragment

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar();
```

Comment: toolbar is always null when I tried to to something with

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private Toolbar toolbar;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getLayoutResource());
    configureToolbar();
  }

  protected abstract int getLayoutResource();

  private void configureToolbar() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    // changes made here, try to find if getSupportActionBar() is null or not after setting it - setSupportActionBar 

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
  }

 // How and where you calling this method ?
 public void hideToolbar() {
   toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 }
```

Comment: now there is no error, but when I call .hideToolbar, toolbar is still there

Comment: use in this in `MyFragment` -> `((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();`

Comment: remove abstract from class and try not to extand baseactivity.

Comment: still not working, I don't know where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

To access `ActionBar` from `Fragment` try the below method

```
ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```

You can now access all the methods of `ActionBar`